Solving the system $\frac{xy}{ay+bx}=c$, $\frac{xz}{az+cx}=b$, $\frac{yz}{bz+cy}=a$ for $x$, $y$, $z$
I came across a question regarding sytems of linear equations. I have tried elimination,substituition and simon's factoring trick etc but still not able to extract x,y,z.
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{ay + bx} = c \\[4pt]
\dfrac{xz}{az + cx} = b \\[4pt]
\dfrac{yz}{bz + cy} = a
\end{cases} 
$$
Solve the given system of equations and represent x,y,z in terms of a,b,c

Successive elimination works fine

$$\dfrac1c=\dfrac ax+\dfrac by$$  so, can be linear in  $1/x.1/y,1/z$
But I could not find the rest $3$ unknowns
